# How do I add a subclass to a List<superclass> in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have a superclass called Thing (I know it's not specific) that inherits from Object:

```
class Thing: Object {
    dynamic var title: String = ""

    var parents: [Thing] {
        return linkingObjects(Thing.self, forProperty: "children")
    }

    let children = List<Thing>()
}
```

and two subclasses of that called Task and Thought.

However, when I do

```
someThing.children.append(Task())
```

it throws "Object type is incorrect."

What am I doing wrong?  Does realm not allow subclasses in lists of superclasses because that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Did you try someThing.children.append(Task() as Thing)?

Comment: yes, it still crashed with the same error

Comment: Did you try to change `let children` to `var children`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Realm's inheritance mapping doesn't support yet polymorphism. You would need either dedicated lists with a concrete subclass as generic parameter or a whole different approach of inheritance mapping.